# Writing URLs to cells without quotes using Google Sheets API

Tags: node.js, url, google-sheets

I'm writing URL values to a spreadsheet using the Google Sheets API.
These values are being stored as Strings but I need them to be created as URL links.
The 3rd party software reading the Sheet does not recognize these strings as URL values and fails.
I can get it to work if I hand-edit the fields and remove the surrounding quotes.
How can I write these so they are not saved with quotes around them?

Comment: Can you provide your current script?

Answer (score 0):

The client is using Node-Red (not my choice) and the relevant code is scattered across several nodes. It turns out I was passing through a "quoted" link from a html response object (should have realized) when I thought it was was not quoted. I spent several hours rewriting it in pure node.js before I realized what the problem was. So... programmer debugging error.